# How to remove a selected item from ListView using CursorAdapter

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-cursoradapter

I am using `CursorAdapter` and below is my adapter class. My list consists of two text views and one button on each row. Now, on click of the button I want to delete the selected item from the list as well as from the database. How can I get the id of the selected item from the database so that I can delete it and then notify the adapter (refresh the list).

```
public class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    Cursor c;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        this.c = c;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

        TextView txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        txtName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Helper.tbl_col_username)));
        TextView txtPassword = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        txtPassword.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Helper.tbl_col_password)));

        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Button Click ");
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null); 
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: As per your listview bind with cursor and if you are managing the cursor with activity then on onListItemClick gives you the _ID which you want to but here you are trying to get a _ID on button's click in bindView then you have to fetch the ID at before the your button's click using _ID column name and pass it to your button's click, and use it.. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try some thing like this :

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    TextView txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    txtName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Helper
                                                           .tbl_col_username)));
    TextView txtPassword = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
    txtPassword.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Helper
                                                           .tbl_col_password)));

    final String itemId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));

    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Button Click ");
            deleteRecordWithId(itemId);
            cursor.requery();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `cursor.requery()` is deprecated now

Answer (score 2):

Im assuming this ID is in the cursor.  Then simply make your own class DeleteEntryOnClicklistener which implements OnClickListener and let it take the ID in its constructor, and deletes the entry when clicked.

Please comment if I have misunderstood your problem or if Im being unclear, cheers :)

edit:

In  your `bindView()`, change the OnClicklistener to something like this:

```
long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Helper.tbl_col_id));
button.setOnClicklistener(new DeleteEntryOnClicklistener(id));
```

And `DeleteEntryOnClicklistener` should look something like this:

```
public class DeleteEntryOnClicklistener implements View.OnClickListener {

    long id;

    public DeleteEntryOnClicklistener(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        database.deleteEntry(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: yes you are right, my id is in the cursor and I want to fetch the id from the item that is selected, so how to do that.

Comment: I edited my answer a bit, perhaps it is a bit clearer now how I imagined the code.

Comment: hmmm that seems fine, how about re-populating the list or refresh the list?

Comment: well may be i came up couple of years later, but the prolem with above solution is that when once a row is deleted from the listview, its position changes. but its column id in the database doesnt as it is autoincrement