# how to remove selected item from listview using CursorAdapter

Tags: java, android

buttononclicklistener is not working,how to delete the selected item from list

```
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //TestDBAdapter.deleteEntry(itemId);
    TestDBAdapter.delete("TABLE_NAME", "_id="+itemId, null);                    
    Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this, "you want delete this item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    cursor.requery();
    updateList();   
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Refer this links, it may helps you, http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/06/edit-row-in-sqlite-database-using.html http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/how-to-update-and-delete-data-from-sqlite-database-in-android/

Comment: Post `TestDBAdapter` source code

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,,

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    TextView txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    txtName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Helper.tbl_col_username)));
    TextView txtPassword = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
    txtPassword.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Helper.tbl_col_password)));

final String itemId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));

    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Button Click ");
            deleteRecordWithId(itemId);
            cursor.requery();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

also refer this link, [How to remove a selected item from ListView using CursorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416389/how-to-remove-a-selected-item-from-listview-using-cursoradapter)

Comment: Bad idea. `cursor.requery()` is deprecated now

Answer (score 0):

Other possibility of refresh data in a CursorAdapter backed ListView is to create a new cursor and call swapCursor on CursorAdapter.

```
  cursor = newCursor();
  ((CursorAdapter) getListAdapter()).swapCursor(cursor);
```

Hope this can help.