# Android - Delete item within ListActivity

Tags: android, android-listview, listactivity

I have a Delete button next to each list item in my `ListActivity` class, and in my delete button i have `android:onClick="myClickHandler"`. Right now, i am working on my code within my `myClickHandler` function to successfully delete the selected list item. Could someone please give me advice in how i can reference in my code as to which item is being deleted, as well as delete the item upon being clicked? I've provided my `ListActivity` code.. Thanks for all and any responses!

```
public class LyricList extends ListActivity {

private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;
private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
private LyricsDbAdapter mDbHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lyriclist);
    mDbHelper = new LyricsDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    fillData();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

private void fillData() {
    Cursor lyricsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllLyrics();
    startManagingCursor(lyricsCursor);
    String[] from = new String[]{LyricsDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};
    SimpleCursorAdapter lyrics = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.lyrics_row, lyricsCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(lyrics);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case INSERT_ID:
            createLyric();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

public void myClickHandler(View v) 
{
    ListView lvItems = getListView();
    for (int i=0; i < lvItems.getChildCount(); i++) 
    {
        //incorrectly implemented...getting errors within this
        LinearLayout vwParentRow = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
        Button Delbtn = (Button)vwParentRow.getChildAt(1);
        DELETE_ID:
        mDbHelper.deleteLyric(lvItems.getChildAt(i)); 

    }

}

private void createLyric() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(LyricsDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    fillData();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. Delete it from the DB.
2. Call requery() on the Cursor.
3. Call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter.

Edit:  In order to get the ID you should override the bindView function of the adapter, and attach your OnClickListener in there.

[How to remove a selected item from ListView using CursorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416389/how-to-remove-a-selected-item-from-listview-using-cursoradapter)