# How do i remove songs from my ArrayList after deletion?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, mediastore

So after i delete a song from the `MediaStore`, it still remains as an item in the `ListView`. On top of this, the song is still playable and will only be removed completely (as a MediaStore and ListItem entry) if the app is restarted.

Therefore the code does work, however, i'm trying to get it to work within the app itself rather than having to restart it each time. This is what i'm currently doing...

```
String strSongID = Long.toString(songID);

Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, strSongID);
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID+ "=?" ;
String[] selectionArgs = {strSongID};

getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(uri, selection, selectionArgs);

songAdt.notifyDataSetChanged();

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Deleted Song", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Any tips? Thanks!

### Edit

Deleting the `ArrayList` item didn't fix the problem as only the `ListItem` in the adapter was removed. The MediaStore entry was still present.

Comment: notify change to your adapter

Comment: Still the same result, unfortunately.

Comment: you have to remove the same from your `ArrayList` also and then call `notifyDataSetChange()` on your adapter

Comment: How would i do that? Do i need to delete the specific ArrayList item?

Comment: Yes remove item from arrayList, or better use cursor adapter, it will do automatically

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example of the cursor adapter?

Comment: follow any code such as https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter

Comment: refer this answer on stackoverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8430107/6127411

Comment: Removing the ArrayList item didn't work. I just tested it with no luck.